# the count sessionFactory.getStatistics().getTransactionCount() is 0

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, transactions

This question is to improve my understanding of how the transactions are managed within the sessions in spring hibernate. When I print getSessionFactory()getStatistics().getTransactionCount() , it prints '0' when getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive() is 'true'. I am really confused. Kindly clear the same for me .

Following is the piece of code in which I want the transaction to happen:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public int insertNewRecord(){
System.out.println(getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive());//gives `true`
System.out.println(getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getStatistics()); //Gives statistics
System.out.println(getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getSessionOpenCount());// Gives 1
System.out.println(getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getTransactionCount());// Gives 0
}
```

My spring and Hibernate configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list><value>classpath:Employee.hbm.xml</value></list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- SQL dialect -->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <!-- Enable Hibernate's current session context -->
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop> --><!-- org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext -->

            <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Below is the transaction manager:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you might want to try executing that code a few times, since the [getTransactionCount()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/stat/Statistics.html#getTransactionCount%28%29) method is documented as:

> The number of transactions we know to have completed

So if you started with zero, but then you take a count in the middle of a transaction, the transaction has not completed yet, so the count would still be zero.

You might also want to add a call to [isStatisticsEnabled()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/stat/Statistics.html#isStatisticsEnabled%28%29) and print the result, just to double-check that stats are enabled.

Comment: @Nicholas. Thanks.. for me statistics were not enabled by default. They can be enabled via the config file (hibernate.generate_statistics=on) or programmatically sessionFactory.getStatistics().setStatisticsEnabled(true)

Comment: Good call. Sometimes all your ducks have to be in a row for anything to work.....  :)